# XFX HD 7950 fans spin 100% but no picture in 3 diff PC

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, vga

I have recently bought a used XFX HD 7950 and the following things happen: 
1. PC seem to start up normally
2. BIOS screen comes in, VGA fans go 100% and the display goes off saying "Check video cable"

The strongest power supply I tried with was a 700W Corsair which normally runs a stronger card. When I check the heat on the card by hand (after disconnecting all power source ofc) it has got a normal temp. 
What could be the issue?

Comment: sound like you need to RMA it.

Comment: When does the display go off exactly? Are you trying to boot an operating system? (The display may just be going off because the OS is disabling the video card.)

Comment: I can see the bios screen, and like 8/10 times i can go into the bios itself. Then just *boop* no screen. Im trying to boot a Win7 64 bit, and I am currently using a HD6670 in the same slot.

Comment: Make sure your BIOS isn't configured to use a motherboard/CPU integrated video device. if there is the option to disable onboard or onchip video, try using it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of things that could be happening.

1. Are you sure the GPU is compatible with your system?  Do they use different PCI specifications etc.
2. Is your BIOS configured properly, check to see which option your motherboard is using as the primary graphics card.
3. Try reseating the card, it's a big card and when turned sideways can often fall out of the PCI Express slot.
4. You mention a 700 Watt PSU, but didn't explicitly say that the necessary power cables are plugged into the GPU, make sure everything is plugged in properly.
5. Have you tried a different port on the card?  Or a different monitor and cable?  Maybe the card is outputting in a resolution that the monitor can't handle.

Does the computer work with a different card?

Comment: 1. Yes 2.Yes 3.Tried several times 4. Yes 5. Yes.

Answer (score -2):

First I would try removing the heatsink, applying paste, and re-seating it.  As its used, I assume it was shipped to you and rough enough handling could have broken the chip to heatsink "bond".  Without a heatsink, a beefy gfx card could be instantly overheating.

I had a card do the same to me years ago and I brought it back to life with the old bake in the oven trick.  Risky of course, and be very careful, but if nothing else works: http://lifehacker.com/5823227/save-dying-video-cards-with-a-quick-bake-in-the-oven

Make sure ALL plastic is off the card.  It will probably smell a little burny, but that is normal.  Make sure your oven doesn't under-report its temperature and turn the oven off immediately if you see any hint of smoke.  I wouldn't do more than 10 minutes either.

Once its done and fully cooled off (couple hours - let it cool slowly so nothing cracks), make sure to use a quality thermal paste when putting the heatsink assembly back on.

Comment: I would not recommend either of these suggestions.  Removing the heatsink will void any warranty you might have and actually have a decent chance of damaging the GPU core.  The heatsink is not designed to be user replaceable, it's quite fragile compared to a standard CPU heatsink.  The baking idea is a long shot and I personally would not ever feel comfortable doing that.

Comment: OP said he bought it used, so warranty is likely not an option.  They also stated that other cards work in the same machine, even ones with higher power requirements.  So more drastic measures are about the only options left other than use it as a paperweight.

Comment: I bought it with a water cooling unit on it and I changed it back to the factory air cooling by myself. Havent tried it with the water cooling unit. I spent too much money to not care about it. And again You CAN go into the BIOS and I managed to go until the "Welcome" screen once. And then the screen goes off, but the fans keep spinning and the card is not overheated.